# Can an Excel macro assigned to a shape format the cell the shape is sitting on?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to treat a column of cells as buttons where you click one and its font/fill change to show it is selected and formatting clears from the other "buttons". It would seem that dropping rectangles on each cell and assigning them to some `cell_on` macro would do the trick, but I do not know how to make the macro reference the underlying cells dynamically. Using `ActiveCell` does not work because when clicking on an overlaid shape the cell beneath is not actually selected.

Comment: You could use [`Shape.TopLeftCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.topleftcell).

Answer (score 1):

You can use hyperlinks like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("#tester()","            ")
```

Just has empty display text, and you can remove the underline formatting.

The links call this function

```
'in a regular module
Function tester()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A17").Interior.Color = vbYellow '<< clear rest of range
    Selection.Interior.Color = vbRed  '<< set the clicked cell
    Set tester = Selection '<< must return a range
End Function
```

Comment: Ok so with this approach I don't bother with shapes, correct?

Comment: Yes, so you don't have any worries about shapes shifting, sorting, etc etc

Comment: Works great although HYPERLINK won't accept any formula for the jump text, only a string or a cell reference.
Besides that, is `tester` now a global variable I can call from a macro?

Comment: `=HYPERLINK("#tester()",D2 & " " & E2)` (for example) works fine for me.  What type of fomula were you wanting to use?  `tester` is a function - you could call it from a macro but not sure why you'd want to, as it's pretty specific to this use case.

Comment: Figured out formula isssue: had to drop `=` from the front